# Solution verification about proof involving equivalent statements related to continuity in metric spaces

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X_{1}, d_{1})$ and $(X_{2}, d_{2})$ be metric spaces and $f:X_{1}\to X_{2}$ a function.

Given that $x\in X$, prove the following statements are equivalent

(a) $f$ is continuous $x$.

(b) for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f[B^{X_{1}}_{\delta}(x)]\subset B^{X_{2}}_{\varepsilon}(f(x))$.

In order to prove the direction $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$, I considered the following definition of continuity:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists\delta > 0)(\forall y\in X_{1})(d_{1}(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{2}(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

This means that, no matter what neighborhood $B^{X_{2}}_{\varepsilon}(f(x))$ one chooses, there is a neighborhood $B^{X_{1}}_{\delta}(x)$ such that the inclusion $f[B^{X_{1}}_{\delta}(x)]\subset B^{X_{2}}_{\varepsilon}(f(x))$ holds.

Conversely, suppose that (b) holds and we want to prove (a).

The proposed statement says that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that, if $d_{1}(x,y) < \delta$, then $d_{2}(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon$, and the corresponding definition is true.

The problem with my ''proof'' is that it sounds tautological.

Having said that, can anyone help me to provide a correct proof?

Comment: I am unable to help you, since I see nothing wrong with your proof.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: And here's your fist upvote. The first of many, I hope.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you =)

Comment: It "sounds tautological" because what you were asked to prove is just a notation change on the definition. This isn't a problem with your proof. There just wasn't much to prove.